# 11 6 [Error] name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

int a[9][9], b[9][9];

int inputvalue(int x, int y, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (value == b[x][i] || value == b[i][y])
            return 0;
    }
    for (i = (x / 3) * 3; i <= ((x / 3) * 3) + 2; i++)
        for (int j = (y / 3) * 3; j <= ((y / 3) * 3) + 2; j++)
            if (b[i][j] == value)
                return 0;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`i` won't survive the first for loop. You should declare it before You do anything or declare it again in the second loop.

To understand it, use google with "c", "variable", "scope" keywords

Answer (score 4):

Because variables defined in the `for` construct is usable in that `for` loop only.

That said, variable `i` in

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++){ 
    if (value==b[x][i] || value==b[i][y])
        return 0;
}
```

cannot be used in

```
for (i=(x/3)*3; i<=((x/3)*3)+2; i++)
    for (int j=(y/3)*3; j<=((y/3)*3)+2; j++)
        if (b[i][j]==value)
            return 0;
```

To fix this, you may declare the variable `i` again in the second loop, and for the second loop only. Change

```
for (i=(x/3)*3; i<=((x/3)*3)+2; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=(x/3)*3; i<=((x/3)*3)+2; i++)
```

Alternatively, you may define `i` at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

change `for (i = (x / 3) * 3; i <= ((x / 3) * 3) + 2; i++)` to `for (int i = (x / 3) * 3; i <= ((x / 3) * 3) + 2; i++)`, `i` definition will only lasts in first `for` loop