# Is it wrong to use a for loop variable outside the loop?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, scope

For example, consider this code :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ );

    // USING i OUTSIDE for LOOP
    std::cout << i;    
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile it under g++, it says **"name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping, (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)"**

I think the problem is scoping. The variable i is declared in for scope and is being used outside it. Our teacher permits doing this when i asked. **Is it wrong?**

Comment: Yes, I think it's wrong - that's why it warns about you using scoping rules that's not part of the standard.

Comment: The standard changed, and this is no longer part of the standard. If you declare `i` before the `for`, then you can use it. (In other words, follow the standard and declare `i` before the `for` if you want to use `i` outside the loop).

Comment: @crashmstr Yea that i know, but was it part of standard before? i mean for variable's scope earlier was global? avtually our teacher in school uses turbo c++ so that may be the reason.

Comment: Ok, just run as fast as possible from Turbo C++. It is ancient and does not support any reasonable modern C++ standards (Turbo C++ has iostream.h and *not* iostream for one thing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124062/116-error-name-lookup-of-i-changed-for-iso-for-scoping-fpermissive

Comment: In MSVC6 this has been the case. Using two for loops with the same variable name lead to redifinition errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **ISO 'for' scoping** refers to the C++ standard. In an old standard (or, more likely, old compilers that supported it), the scope of loop variables was the scope enclosing the for statement. However, this changed, which is why you are getting that error.

A general hint about this kind of error mentioning **-fpermissive**: The constructs leading to these messages are usually (long) obsolete, and were allowed by either an old standard or an old compiler. Because of this, there exists old code that depends on obsolete behaviour. You shouldn't write new code that requires that option; it is more of a quick fix to get legacy code running on new GCC versions quickly.

Comment: Was there even a **standard** where the scope of the loop variable was the scope enclosing the for statement? It doesn't sound sound that the standard would turn a valid program invalid. Isn't it just an extension that some compiler supported (fx GCC) before this was included in the standard?

Comment: @skyking you are probably right. I vaguely remember this being true, but I can't find any reference regarding that right now. So I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is wrong.
If you want to use a value outside of a loop, define it outside of the loop.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<10; ++i);
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` is not defined outside the loop. This leads to a compile-time error.
You can do this instead:

```
int i = 0;
for(i; i < 10; ++i);

std::cout << i;
```

In that case, `i` is defined outside the `for-loop`, so I can "see" it

Answer (score 0):

yeah it's no where possible to use the variables declare inside a for loop with all the changes in effect in the modern C++ Standards. for more detail you can always refer to cplusplus.com which is a site that contains all information based on the recent changes in the standards.
A personal advice would be to you that don't just blindly go with the suggestions others make, explore on your own and then imitate the changes.